# Oracle Forms 12c integration with BI Publisher

Tags: oracle, oracleforms, bi-publisher, oraclereports, oracle-bi

There is a tutorial that explains in detail, how is the integration of oracle bi publisher with oracle forms 12c.
Oracle forms 12c comes with the possibility of integrating oracle reports as well as oracle bi publisher, it would be very helpful if you pass me some tutorial, page or document explaining this process.

I have found a lot of information but unfortunately it is outdated, therefore, if the information is current, it is still better

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a outline of new features in 12c, integration with BI Publisher starts on Page 4.  (warning: it is a .PDF)  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/forms/documentation/oracleforms-12210-newfeatures-2906037.pdf

Found the PDF on the following Oracle Blog post: https://blogs.oracle.com/proactivesupportdevtools/oracle-forms-12c-integration-with-bi-publisher (scroll down to "'Oracle BI-Publisher Integration' from Oracle Forms 12c New Features – Rev. 1")

Comment: thanks! it is very helpful!
But i have one more question, this tutorial works with a Oracle BI-Publisher 11g trial!
At the moment I don´t have the full versions of bi publisher, but there is a trial version with which I am doing tests.
Will it work too?

Comment: Happy to help :) I can't speak to the differences between the full and trial versions, but I would wager that there is a lot of crossover. If your organization has a ULA with Oracle, I would recommend checking with the department responsible to see if you can get assistance with setting up a test environment. If you're doing some *independent* testing, just try to get as far as you can. If nothing else, see if there are virtual system images you can use to test using virtualbox or a comparable application.

Comment: Hello again
I wanted to ask you to see if you know if I can access from oracle forms 12c to any report in any version of oracle bi publisher?
Because in this case, I'm using Oracle BI Publisher 11g Trial Edition (v11.1.1.7.1), the problem would be that it can only be done with the latest version of oracle bi publisher.
Do you know anything about that?

Comment: It depends on which version of the report you're trying to run. Oracle Forms has minimum requirements like most Oracle products, and you won't be able to just use any version of BI Publisher. I imagine you would have better results using the 12c version of Publisher, but if that's not an option, I would recommend checking the documentation for any compatibility issues that might arise. (Documentation can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/html/E25460_02/r2_fr_requirements.htm) If Oracle is telling you that it's only possible with the latest version of BI Publisher, you're out of luck

Comment: I see, I read all the document already but it do not say anything about compatibility so i gonna try to download an offical oracle bi publisher 11g or 12c to do the same test